# PowerShell method Contains not working as expected

Tags: powershell

I am very new to PowerShell and I need to prepare some PowerShell commands to a assign users some roles in Exchange Online. I first need to check if the user is assigned the role already and if not, I'll assign the role. But I just can't figure out how to check if one email address is part of list of email addresses.

I found many discussions on `-contains` or `.Contains` method not working but their solutions never worked for me. My code is below.

```bsh
$L1Group = Get-MsolGroup | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -eq "TEST_GROUP"}
$L1Members = Get-MsolGroupMember -GroupObjectId $L1Group.ObjectId
$CurrentMembers = Get-RoleGroupMember "Recipient Management" |
                  Select -Property WindowsLiveID
foreach ($user in $L1Members) {
    if (!$CurrentMembers.Contains($user.EmailAddress)) {  
        Add-RoleGroupMember "Recipient Management" -Member $user.EmailAddress
    }
}
```

It works fine without the `if` statement and it assigns roles as expected, but I need to skip users who are already members of the role group. I just cant figure out how to make the `if` statement work. If I use `echo $CurrentMembers` it returns list of 4 email addresses, just as expected and even if I try

```bsh
$CurrentMembers -contains 'MyEmail@MyDomain.com'
```

it always returns False but the address is in the list.

Comment: Just out of curiosity why are you skipping those with the role already? If they contain the role it'll simply state that and move on assuming you're looping through everyone

Comment: It is mostly because PowerShell will return like 5 lines of red text for each user who already has the permission (
The recipient "email@domain.com" is already a member of the group "Recipient Management". and few more lines)

Comment: This is true but functionality should still work, understandable why you'd want to avoid though.

Comment: Ye, as I stated in my post, the script works, but i need to hand it over to someone who will run it evey time they hire new members and I dont want them to see 40 times 5 red lines every time - since they would miss any actual error :-(

Comment: `Select -Property WindowsLiveID` -> `Select -Expand WindowsLiveID`

Comment: Wow, seems like this solves my problem. Thank you very much. Can I somehow mark it as a solution or does it have to be posted as new answer?

Comment: .contains() acts differently whether $currentmembers is one element or more than one, but it should work ok in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't work the way you expect because this statement

```
$CurrentMembers = Get-RoleGroupMember "Recipient Management" |
                  Select -Property WindowsLiveID
```

produces a list of custom objects with a single property `WindowsLiveID`, but your check expects a list of strings. Expand the property to get that list of strings:

```
$CurrentMembers = Get-RoleGroupMember "Recipient Management" |
                  Select -Expand WindowsLiveID
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common question.  .contains and -contains are different.  $CurrentMembers may contain sub-properties.

```
PS C:\Users\admin\foo> 'hi there'.contains('hi')
True
PS C:\Users\admin\foo> 'hi','there' -contains 'hi'
True
```

Does this work?  Another common question is how to get just the value from the property.

```
if (! ($CurrentMembers.windowsliveid -Contains $user.EmailAddress) )
```

Hmm, interesting how .contains() works with arrays.  It's more like -contains.  More confusion!

```
PS C:\Users\js\foo> $a = 'one','two','three'
PS C:\Users\js\foo> $a.contains('one')
True
PS C:\Users\js\foo> $a.contains('o')
False
PS C:\Users\js\foo> $a.contains

OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
bool IList.Contains(System.Object value)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have read few discussions where they explained difference between -contains and .contains, but neither is working in my case

Answer (score 0):

Solution is in comments - "Select -Property WindowsLiveID -> Select -Expand WindowsLiveID"

– Ansgar Wiechers 2 hours ago

Hopefully Angsar will post an answer so he can get credit...

Here's a link to the M$oft doc for the Select-Object cmdlet:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-6